# jQuery(html, props) not working on an input

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

The jQuery overload for creating an HTML element and supplying a map of properties does not seem to work for  controls. I saw in the documentation that IE does not allow you to change the type so you have to specify that, but it seems to ignore everything in the properties map in IE and Chrome:

```
$("<input type='text'>", {
    id: "foo",
    name: "foo",
    value: "test"
}).appendTo("body");
```

Is creating the following element:

```
<input type="text" />
```

JSFiddle demonstrating the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/JyvBh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the type as part of the other attributes and it will work; like this:

```
$("<input>", {
    type: "text",
    id: "foo",
    name: "foo",
    value: "test"
}).appendTo("body");​
```

**EDIT: Suportted Workaround According to jQuery Docs**

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) the workaround actually uses a different format as below:

```
$('<input type="text" />').attr({
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'foo',
    value: 'test'
}).appendTo("body");
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JyvBh/3/) including both methods above.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wait, there was a whole section in the documentation that said this wasn't supported in IE, so I wrote it to match what their documentation said - but this does seem to work in IE? That's weird...

Comment: @Dismissile The workaround section shows a different format to be used for IE – I've included it in the answer above. My guess is that, as this was introduced in jQuery 1.4 the now working format didn't work with previous versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you write like this:

```
$("<input>", {
    type : "text",
    id: "foo",
    name: "foo",
    value: "test"
}).appendTo("body");​
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way

```
$("<input />", {
    type:'text',
    id: "foo",
    name: "foo",
    value: "test"
}).appendTo("body");​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tBbBf/).